# Angular, is there a way to call a component 3 times with different text?

Tags: angular

I have a component on angular that I want it to appear 3 times and with different text each time. Is there a way to do this? Component is a simple bootstrap card. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Input() text: string` in your component.

And then you can just do:

```
<app-component [text]="'text 1'"></app-component>
<app-component [text]="'text 2'"></app-component>
<app-component [text]="'text 3'"></app-component>
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to angular... so this text would be in the component.html and also inside the component.ts file inside `constructor() { }` which is inside `@export`?

Comment: I did an example for you, you can check the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yd1a9h?file=src/app/app.component.html). If you have any question tell me. I give you this link for the documentation as well: [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)